# Need help on a program that generate 1000 random integers between 0 and 9 and use count

Tags: python

How to code a program that will generate 1000 random integers between 0 and 9 and displays the count for each # say counts, to store the counts for the number 0s 1s ...... 9s

Here's my code

```
i = list(range(0,1000,9)) 
print (i) 
i = len(i) 
print (i)
```

Comment: i = list(range(0,1000,9))

print (i)
i = len(i)
print (i)

but when i run it i forgot the count and i dont know how to use it. i'm just a beginner sorry

Comment: Show your code here so we can see how are you doing wrong in your code. StackOverflow does not produce any code for you. To get a program you need to hire a Programmer or Freelancer.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `randint` function from random to generate an integer and store it in a `Counter`.

Documentation on the `Counter` collection is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

```
from collections import counter
from random import randint
c = Counter()
for i in range(1000):
    rint = randint(0,9)
    c[rint] += 1
print c
```

Comment: If it works I'd appreciate it if you'd mark my answer as correct so other people with the same problem will know that it works. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
dic = {k: 0 for k in range(10)}
for i in range(1000):
    num = randint(0, 9)
    dic[num] += 1

print dic
```

You can use a dictionary to keep the count as well